# How to check the query string of my current url for a specific key-value pair?

Tags: php, if-statement, url, query-string, isset

How I can identify in PHP if my current URL contains this text `special_offer=12`.
For example, if my domain URL is `http://www.example.com/newproducts.html?special_offer=12` then echo something.

Alternatively, the domain can be `http://example.com/all-products.html?at=93&special_offer=12`

This text will always be the same: `special_offer=12`.

Comment: Use `!empty()` .. to check `special_offer` parameter var is `== 12` or not ., bcoz `isset()`  also accept the null value so in that case `isset()` is failed !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the Query parameters using the $_GET superglobal, In this case:

```
if(isset($_GET['special_offer']) && $_GET['special_offer'] == 12){ 
  echo "Something";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['special_offer'] {
   do something...
}
```

Write `var_dump($_GET);`
to see how superglobal $_GET works

Answer (score 0):

Just by checking the $_GET var ?

```
if(!empty($_GET["special_offer"]) && $_GET["special_offer"] ==12 ){
    //You're code here
}
```

Comment: `if` is lowercase and `$_GET` is uppercase!

Comment: I'm on smartphone :).

Answer (score -1):

> You Can Access To Query Parameter Using `Get` Like This:

```
if(isset($_GET['special_offer'] == 12)){ 

  //echo " ECHO YOUR CODE HERE ";

}
```

OR

### NOTE:  **Avoid To Use `isset()` and  USE `!empty()` ..Because `isset()` accept the `null` value also to store , So avoid to use it !!**

```
 if(!empty($_GET['special_offer']) && $_GET['special_offer'] == 12){ 
    
      //echo " ECHO YOUR CODE HERE ";
    
    }
```

> **NOTE:**

`Empty` checks if the variable is set and if it is it checks it for null, "", 0, etc

> 1 `Isset` just checks if is it set, it could be anything not null
>
> 2 With `empty`, the following things are considered empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Hi I check your code and I have this Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: you can use `!empty()` then

Comment: @Robert .. you can use `!empty()`